# Disable AJAX Load of Content via Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, routes

I have a custom plugin that was originally loading html content via ajax into the page by appending a hash marker and page ID to the URL.

I am very new to this level of complexity and would like to 'undo' this functionality, so the plugin can initialize without the Router function. I've been looking at this for a couple days and am pretty lost...

The entire plugin seems to be initialized by this function. Any tips or suggestions on how to turn 'off' this feature, so the code still initializes without appending the # to the URL would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {

var connections = [],
    IEversion = detectIE(),
    killConnections = null,
    node = null,
    randomBehaviour,
    rootIndex = 1,
    silentRoute = null;

// Splash.
var splash = {
    init: function() {
        $('#splash').addClass('active');
        $('.node.splash').draggable({
            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function() {
                if(!splash.destroyed) {
                    $('.node.splash').addClass('dragging');
                    splash.destroy('drag');
                    splash.destroyed = true;
                }
            },
            scroll: false,
            disabled: false
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            if($('.arrow').is(':visible')) {
                splash.destroy();
            }
        }, 4000);
    },
    destroy: function(event) {
        if(event === 'drag') {
            $('.arrow').hide();
        } else {
            $('.arrow').fadeOut(500);
        }
        $('#splash-wrapper p, .node.splash').fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#splash').remove();
            nody.init();
        }, 500);
    },
    destroyed: false
};

// Router.
var routes = {
    '/': function() {
        if(!splash.destroyed) {
            splash.init();
        }else {
            nody.unloadMenu();
        }
    }
};

var router = Router(routes);

router.configure({
    strict: false,
    before: function() {
        if(silentRoute) {
            silentRoute = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}).init('/');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy answer-

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

Using jQuery Mobile.

Detail is **[here](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/jquery-mobile/tip-disable-ajax-on-jquery-mobile-forms/)**.

If u want to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), then there is not a direct way of doing it.

So u should use a global variable for doing it like this way-

```js
var is_ajax_enabled = true;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    ...................
    ...................
    $("selector").click(function()
    {
        ...................
        //before AJAX call, just do a checking like it-
        if(is_ajax_enabled())
        {
          //make your AJAX call here
          $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result)
          {
            $("#div1").html(result);
          }});
        }
        ...................
    });
    ...................
    ...................
});

function disable_ajax()
{
    is_ajax_enabled=false;
}

function enable_ajax()
{
    is_ajax_enabled=true;
}

function is_ajax_enabled()
{
    return is_ajax_enabled;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Update-

If u want to have only one request available at a time and make a queue for the request, u can try this [jQuery-Ajax-Singleton](https://github.com/dougle/jQuery-Ajax-Singleton) like this way-

```
$.ajax(options || {})
```

Comment: Appreciate the guidance... My question is around _not_ requiring the Router variable at the end of the statement. I no longer need this functionality. I just need to initialize the script without that requirement.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not a direct way of that using jQuery, u should have use jQuery mobile instade of that as I told earlier of this answer

Comment: Check the update of the question, as far as I know these are the way u have in your hand

Comment: Yes, was going through the docs... Think I have it sorted based on your rec using jQuery mobile